# How to paginate list of wp pages?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Ok I have this code:

```
<ul id="page-list">
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=post_date&show_date=created&sort_order=DESC&title_li=&date_format=Y/m/d'); ?>
</ul>
```

How do I add pagination? I want to show only 50 rows of this list on the first page.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `wp_list_pages`